# Evaluating the statistical significance of survey's responses

Tags: survey, validation

I'm a teacher doing some basic research but I'm out of my waters in anything statistical. Recently I submitted a paper based on a student survey which aimed at evaluating the impact of a new pedagogical tool that we are deploying.

Students were asked to answer questions about the tool using several scales (e.g. 1-5, Yes/No, and so on).

The questions were grouped by "research question", but these were more like "topics" to group students' anwsers. Each of these topics was associated with 4 or 5 questions in the questionnaire. For example, one of the "research questions" was related with students being able to use the tool without specific prior training. Under this topic had questions such as "How much time did using the tool to solve the tasks take?", which had options such as "1- 1 hour, 2- A few hours, ..., 4- Many hours, 5- I am unable to use the tool in a productive way". Another question in this topic was "Do you feel that the time take to execute the tasks using the tool has been reducing over time?". The scale for this specific question was: "1-No, the execution time did not reduce over time" to "5-Yes, the executing time reduced significantly over time".

The paper then presented the survey's results in a very basic fashion: for each question, we presented the frequency of each option (e.g. "option 1 was selected by 10% of the students, option 2 was selected by 20% of the students") and then we drew some conclusions (e.g. "the majority of students seem to agree that ...").

For example, in the example topic, we concluded that students would benefit from some formal training, because: 1) multiple students were not able to use the tool in a useful fashion, 2) the time needed varied a lot between the different students, and 3) the majority of students reported improvements over time, but with varying degrees of improvement.

In the peer review, one of the reviewers mentioned that the paper should have some statistical analysis to evaluate the significance of the results. I don't know how to do perform this, so I'm asking this forum for help.

Can you give me some pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now, this question is far too broad to be answered. But the first step would be to come up with some hypotheses or research questions. Ideally, you would have come up with these before starting to collect data, but that's not possible at this point.  Please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added some more information to the question.